# Inferred particles - should I infer は or に in this sentence?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-は

I was translating this song (https://www5.atwiki.jp/hmiku/pages/31606.html) and there was a line that didn't make sense without an inferred particle, but I'm not sure which particle to infer.

(あの子は私のよう - (I just included this for context))

救いようのない人　恋をしてた

Should I infer it like this:

救いようのない人**は**恋をしてた

"A pathetic person in love."

Or  救いようのない人**に**恋をしてた

"In love with a pathetic person."

Can someone tell me which particle is more commonly inferred, or is more likely in this context?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is ambiguous, but judging from the whole lyrics, I feel I would take this as two sentences:

> - あの人 was helpless.
> - (And) I was in love with him (=あの人).

This effectively is closer to your second interpretation, but the particle に in this place is usually not omitted in ordinary sentences.

I'm saying this because the viewpoint of the whole lyrics is 私. And the second instance of 恋をしてた in the last half of the song is clearly about 私.

Comment: So, do you think あの子 and 救いようのない人 are the same person? It seems strange to me to use 子 and 人 so close to each other to refer to the same person. But that's probably just my perspective as as an native English speaker.

Comment: 子 can be used to refer to teenagers and young adults.